# Trouble rerunning/restarting Android Studio debugger

Tags: android, android-studio

The debugger works pretty fine when I start the emulator in debug mode by clicking the bug icon on the android studio toolbar.All breakpoints are hit.But when I try to rerun the debugger by again clicking on the bug icon,it fires the debugger but this time no breakpoints are hit.It randomly works on 3rd-4th try or I have to close the emulator and start again.What could be the reason?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Could you mention which version you are using?

Comment: is there any error message in ADB logs section?

Comment: Dunno,working perfectly fine on another project.Thanks for support btw!

Comment: I would like to help you, but I'm trying to replicate your problem in my own laptop but it' working fine. Sorry. Maybe, I could suggest you update your ide to 1.4 stable version.